# Change Query Arguments (filter) with jQuery/Ajax or PHP?

Tags: php, jquery, query, javascript, ajax

I have a pretty complex wordpress-site for travelling. There's an "archive-hotels.php", a template for the custom-post-type "Hotels". Inside the CPT is a taxonomy called "City", so we can do this: domain.com/hotels/city. Works perfectly. Now there's a filter on the site, which should filter the shown posts by stuff that the author has added over custom fields (Advanced Custom Fields Plugin) like "Features" or "Price Range".

Now I'm not sure how to filter that query. With PHP? jQuery (there shouldnt be too much posts in hotels/city/)? or Ajax to work that dataload, which will be after years of publishing?

Domain www.business-travelling.de/hotels/hamburg

Comment: So when I search for `.../hotels/hamburg?features=sea-face`, the result should contain only the hotels in Hamburg which face the sea?

Answer (score 1):

The permalink structure you've described above e.g..../hotels/hamburg/features/sea-face isn't really something that could be achieved by using custom fields.  You would be better off creating a new taxonomy called 'features' and populating it with terms like 'sea-facing' and any others.

In order to do queries for multiple taxonomies I would recommend the excellent [Query Multiple Taxonomies plugin by Scribu](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/query-multiple-taxonomies/).  This plugin will let your users build searches that span across more than one taxonomy e.g. city AND feature.

You could either use the filter widget that comes with the plugin or build your own if that doesn't quite cut it.  Think in the long run this will prove simpler than messing around with more complex ajax requests or complex wordpress queries looking for combinations of custom fields.

Comment: This looks pretty nice! Thank you! I don't need a fancy and pretty domain for this! I just want to filter the current query by some custom-field-values. Just like "I just want the user to visit hotels/berlin, click on a few arguments "Whirlpool, WiFi and Breakfast", press "Filter" and a filtered list of posts appear. If this works without Ajax and jQuery, it would be perfect too!"

Comment: To be honest using a custom taxonomy for the features will not only be quicker and easier for you to implement (using the above plugin for filtering) but it will be easier for your client/you to administer in the wordpress backend - e.g. they just have to tick a few boxes in a custom taxonomy panel as opposed to adding in any custom fields.

Comment: Ok I get it. I will shoot for taxonomies. Important is: The new query has to include the current taxonomy, you're in, so you don't get hotels from other towns.

Comment: Yep, it can handle that no problem.  Just bear in mind that you don't have to stick to using the widget that comes with the plugin for filtering - you can build your own if understand how the multiple queries are built.

Comment: Yeah Ive implemented it. Awesome to work with. My one last problem: I had to rewrite my taxonomy-urls like this: /custom-post-type/taxonomy/. So your domains with "?taxonomy=XY" doesnt work :(

Comment: Any particular reason why you've rewritten your taxonomy URLs that way?  If you can go back to defaults then it might make your life easier.  Otherwise this blog post seems to cover what you're talking about (not used the info here so can't fully speak to it's validity): http://thereforei.am/2011/10/28/advanced-taxonomy-queries-with-pretty-urls/

Comment: Ah nice, I used exactly that post :-) I put it back to where it were but I have to keep the custom-post-type in mind. So the plugins output should work with /hotels/ instead of replacing it :-) Can I edit that in the plugin-php or can I edit it somewhere else?

Comment: Not too sure about that one I'm afraid - I've only customised the filter for the plugin via the template system that Scribu uses (Mustache) and by rolling my own.  Think you'll need to dig around in the source if you want to make more advanced alterations (though if you can avoid making changes to the core of the plugin that's always preferable).  Good luck!